# How to bind checbox value in an array using angularjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have list of checkbox which I am binding the value from JSON response at page startup in the following way

```
$scope.LoadScreen = function () {
                    $http.get('http://xxxxx:0000/education/research').
                      then(function (response) {
                          $scope.modelList = response;
                      }, function (response) {
                      });

                } 

<div id="teamCheckboxList" class="checkboxList">
                                <h3>Select Your Model</h3>
                                <div ng-repeat="Test in modelList.data | unique : '_source.ModelName'">
                        <label> 
                            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="modelName.name[Test._source.ModelName]" />
                            <span>{{Test._source.ModelName}}</span>
                        </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

I am trying to store the list of selected values in checkbox after clicking the save button in the below format

```
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Search" ng-click="SaveSearch()" /> 

 $scope.SaveSearch = function () {

                    $scope.modelName = {
                        name: []
                    };
```

When I try to print the $scope.modelName.name , I am getting empty array. I am looking for help to store my checkbox checked values in array format.

Thanks in advance

Comment: By the way, you have an input with `id=chxbox` in a repeated element

Comment: @MichaelP.Bazos I edited it.

Comment: When you click submit you are resetting modelName.name to an empty array.

Comment: Ok. Related to the main problem, I guess that you probably don't wan't to redefine `$scope.modelName` in *SaveSearch*. In the `ng-repeat` block, *modelName* references objects from `modelList.data`, therefore the information about the state of the checkbox should land in `modelList.data`, sync-ed by angular.

Comment: @hesa . I am not sure about it. I am newbie to this technology. We need to declare that variable know.

Comment: @MichaelP.Bazos. I couldn't get your point . I am newbie to this technology. I have edited the variable name for clear understanding. Can you please explain me in detail.

Comment: Initialize `$scope.modelName` in the controller, i.e. outside the call `SaveSearch`. Also, declare the `name` property of *$scope.modelName* as an object: `name: {}`

Comment: @hesa, @Michael. The value getting binded now. If I want to take the number of binded value means . How it can be achieved. I am using the below method to get the count of values binded. `var modelNameLength = $scope.modelName.name.length;`. I am getting length as 0.

Comment: `$scope.modelName.name` is now an object, therefore you can do that with `Object.keys($scope.modelName.name).length`

Comment: @MichaelP.Bazos . Awesome its working fine. Thank you so much.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89645/discussion-between-mangoski-and-michael-p-bazos).